# moving remote files inside ftp in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to ftp file to my remote server and then move those files into another directory in the remote server
The ftp happens correctly but the movement is throwing an error like
550 RNFR command failed.

Can you please help?

My script is

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the version of the xml (eg:- v17.25)"
read version
HOST_FIRST='un01'
HOST_LAST='01'
USER='someuser'
PASSWD='somepassword'
HOST="$HOST_FIRST$FILE$HOST_LAST"
ftp -n $HOST <<-END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd /tmp
put myfile.xml
rename myfile.xml /tmp/test_ftp
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `put myfile.xml` to the tmp dir, why not just

**edit**

Change your script from

```
rename myfile.xml /tmp/test_ftp
```

TO

```
rename myfile.xml test_ftp
```

You have already `put` the file in the `/tmp` directory, which you have already done a `cd /tmp` .

That should work.

**You can't specify a path in an ftp rename command and expect it to be moved as well.**

And sorry, not what you want to here, but **there is no move command in ftp. It is that way for security.**

IHTH.

Comment: I want to move myfile.xml  which is already ftpd in the /tmp folder to another folder (/tmp/test_ftp/)?

Comment: Sorry, not what you want to here, but **there is no move command in ftp** . in your example you have already put the file in the tmp directory. Just rename it. Good luck.